# Vertical align CSS content icon with wrapped text

Tags: html, css

I need to reformat predefined HTML to give me a different layout using CSS. The HTML is returned from the server as an error message and as such I'm unable to change the format.

```css
.server-errors ul {
  list-style: none;
}
.server-errors li:before {
  content: "D";
  font-family: "pictos";
}
```

```html
<div class="server-errors">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <label>Server error message goes here.</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The requirement is to display this with removing the `<li>` dot and replacing it with another (pictos) character which is left and vertically aligned.

I have managed to display the character but am unable to align it vertically as a separate entity.

I need:

```
---------------------------------------
-         Long error message goes     -                                     
-    X    here and it will span       -
-         three lines                 -
---------------------------------------
```

I get:

```
---------------------------------------
- X Long error message goes here and  -                                     
-   will span three lines             -
-                                     -
---------------------------------------
```

I'm not sure what exactly I should be changing or even which part of the CSS to look at to get the effect.

Comment: Have you tried padding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use css3 flexbox.

```
.server-errors li {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
}
```

**Output Image:**

[image: Output Image]

```css
.server-errors ul {
  border: 1px solid black;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 150px;
}
.server-errors li {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
}
.server-errors li:before {
  margin-right: 10px;
  content: "D";
  font-family: "pictos";
}
```

```html
<div class="server-errors">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <label>Long error message goes     -                                     
        -    X    here and it will span       -
        -         three lines</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. Works perfectly with the addition of a padding on the label to space better.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use flexbox:

```
.server-errors li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Or, css table-cell with more browser support:

```
.server-errors li:before,
.server-errors li label {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: The label padding helped with layout, did not think of that.

Comment: @user281921 Yes, either flexbox or table-cell handles equal heights.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.all {
            width: 300px;
            display:flex;
        }
        li {
            list-style: none;
        }
        .side {
            width: 10px;
        }
        .letter {
            width: 100px;
            display:flex;
            justify-content:center;
            align-items:center;
        }
        .all * {
            line-height: 30px;
        }
        .message {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="server-errors">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <div class="all">
                    <div class="side">
                        <span>-</span>
                        <span>-</span>
                        <span>-</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="letter">
                        X
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        Long error message goes here and it will span three lines
                    </div>
                    <div class="side">
                        <span>-</span>
                        <span>-</span>
                        <span>-</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: This will not work. You are changing the HTML here, I can not do that. I get the error message sent to me as snippet of HTML from the server.

Comment: Sorry but without changing html you will not have dashes signs in left and write. Because the top and bottom could be with border dashed style but left and write can not.

Comment: Are another answers true?